# blender sapling tree error; leaves rearrange to one direction

Tags: mesh, sapling-addon

Creating a sapling tree in blender works well, for example this tree below

[image: Normal tree]

However, if I select the leaves and go into edit mode, the leaves become like this

[image: error tree]

at this point, I can undo(ctrl + z) and it will revert back to normal, however most times, going into edit mode is not the cause of the error, I just find that all my trees have become like this and I can't undo it.

from my observation, the tree has changed in such a way that; the origin position of each leaf is only found on the top of the branches.

[image: branch]

I have six trees in this scene, all of them became like this and I don't know why, I only know that I can achieve the same thing by selecting the leaves of a tree and going into edit mode.

I am running  blender 2.9. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue- however, if you go to *Object>Apply>Make Instances Real* you can convert the leaves to an editable mesh.